# Get values of dictionary key as list in list of dict without loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Maybe the title is not clear but let say the input is:

```py
data = [
    {'a':10, 'b': 0, 'c': 2},
    {'a':7, 'b': 4, 'c': 4},
    {'a':4, 'b': 5, 'c': 3}
]
```

how to get output like this **without using loops**:

```py
output = {'a': [10, 7, 4], 'b': [0, 4, 5], 'c': [2, 4, 3]}
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: You could use a comprehension but that uses a "loop" internally, it even has `for` in the syntax. What do you mean by "without using loops"?

Comment: @ArpitSvt haven't tried anything as I dont know how to do that without loop. I searched for answer for I think I am not getting proper keyword to search

Comment: @IainShelvington prpbably some builtin methods. I dont want to write loop myself. If any function uses loop internally, it will be fine as we may need to iterate over the data at some point.

Comment: There is no built-in way to do this. Just write the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use loops, you can use `pandas` which is 3rd party library

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {'a':10, 'b': 0, 'c': 2},
    {'a':7, 'b': 4, 'c': 4},
    {'a':4, 'b': 5, 'c': 3}
]


df = pd.DataFrame(data).to_dict(orient="list")

print(df)
```

Output:

```
{'a': [10, 7, 4], 'b': [0, 4, 5], 'c': [2, 4, 3]}
```

Comment: any builtin way to do that?

Comment: at least I'm not aware of such a method.